# fingerprint authentication and save into local database

Tags: android

can any one take a fingerprint from android mobile and save it to local database please kindly help!
currently i am using this

FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback();

Comment: Hire a programmer, that's all. Stack Overflow is a place where we expect you try before you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save a fingerprint image or template. It is stated by Android in the Fingerprint Section.

The Fingerprint data is stored by android system in the phone at a secure location which is not accessible. You can write an app that gets and stores fingerprint to authenticate the user. You can go through this sample that demonstrates to use registered fingerprints to authenticate the user in your app.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog